# Sets order isomorphic to $[\omega_0, \omega_1)$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $\omega_0$ be the first countable ordinal and $\omega_1$ be the first uncountable ordinal. Use $[0, \omega_1)$ to denote the set of all countable ordinals and hence $\omega_1 = [0, \omega_1)$. Could someone construct a set (**other than the set of ordinals**) that is order isomorphic to the set $[\omega_0, \omega_1)$. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833322), Arthur (in the top post) provided an example, which is the following:

For each $\alpha\in[0, \omega_1)$, let $X_{\alpha}$ be the set of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ , each of which is order isomorphic to $\alpha$, and define $X_{\alpha} < X_{\beta}$ iff $\alpha < \beta$. Then it is claimed that the following set $A$, equipped with the order "<"

$$A = \{X_{\alpha}\,\vert\,\alpha\in[0, \omega_1)\}\hspace{1cm}(\subseteq\mathcal{P}[\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})])$$

is order isomorphic to $[0, \omega_1)$. If we can find a uncountable family of sets (**ideally not subsets of the set of ordinals**) so that the supremum is not in the family and no countable union of elements will be equal to the supremum, will that work for this question?

Comment: Isn't $[\omega_0, \omega_1)$ order isomorphic to $[0, \omega_1)$?

Comment: In fact, $[\alpha,\omega_1)\cong[0,\omega_1)$ for every countable ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: "However, I believe $\omega_1\in A$ in this example because $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})\in A$ is the max element." It's hard to parse what you mean there, but assuming I'm interpreting it right, no, there are no subsets of $\mathbb Q$ of order type $\omega_1$ (for many reasons, the most notable being that $\mathbb Q$ is countable). $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ has subsets of many different order types, and those that are well-ordered have the order type of some $\alpha < \omega_1.$ So it is very far from meeting the criteria for being in $A.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That is my mistake and I should instead say "because $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\in A$, then $\omega_1\in A$".

Comment: @SanaeKochiya "$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\in A$" is also false ...

Comment: @SanaeKochiya and $\omega_1\in A$ makes no sense at all taken literally, though I gather what you are trying to say that is that $A$ has something representing that order type, which is false... again, because the rationals don’t have an uncountable subset (let alone an uncountable well ordered subset),

Comment: @NoahSchweber Since $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ is uncountable and $\bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_0}X_{\alpha}$ is countable, can I then conclude $X_{\omega_0}$ is uncountable? I should state $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is a subset of $A$ instead of an element.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen When saying $\omega_1\in A$, I believed $X_{\omega_0}$ is uncountable because $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}) = X_{\omega_0}\cup\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_0}X_{\alpha}$ is uncountable, and $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_0}X_{\alpha}$ is countable. Hence $X_{\omega_0}$ is uncountable but I am not sure about this. I cannot see different between, for instance, $X_{\omega_0}$ and $X_{\omega_0+1}$

Comment: @SanaeKochiya $X_{\omega_0}$ is the set of all subsets of the rationals that are order isomorphic to $\omega_0$. This is indeed uncountable, but I don't see how that is relevant. $X_{\omega_0+1}$ is the set of all subsets of the rationals that are order isomorphic to $\omega_0+1$ which is a completely different set (in fact disjoint from $X_{\omega_0}$), and is also uncountable. For instance $\mathbb N$ is in the first and $\{1-1/(n+1): n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{1\}$ is in the second. But again, the fact that these sets are uncountable is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I got what you mean and I shouldn't have said "$\omega_1\in A$". The mapping in the original example should map $X_{\alpha}$ to $\alpha$ but not $\vert\,X_{\alpha}\,\vert$. Then I will need to show the mapping $X_{\alpha}\mapsto\alpha$ maps $A$ onto $[0, \omega_1)$

Comment: @SanaeKochiya Sure, the idea is just that any countable well-ordered set can be order-embedded into $\mathbb Q$. (In fact, any countable ordered set whatsoever can be embedded.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131449/discussion-between-sanae-kochiya-and-spaceisdarkgreen).

Comment: You can find arbitrarily many such sets. $[\omega_0,\omega_1)$ is of cardinality $\omega_1$. So any set $A$ of cardinality $\omega_1$ implies a bijection between $A$ and $[\omega_0,\omega_1)$. This bijection then defines an order on $A$ so that these two sets are order isomorphic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map $f(x) = \omega_0 + x$ is an order isomorphism $[0, \omega_1) \to [\omega_0, \omega_1)$.

First, let's prove that it's a bijection. Note that in general, if we have ordinals $a \geq b$, then there exists a unique $c$ such that $a = b + c$. So for all ordinals $a \in [\omega_0, \omega_1)$, there exists a unique $c$ such that $\omega_0 + c = a$. This proves that $f$ is a bijection.

From here, we must show that $f$ is an order isomorphism. Suppose that $x \leq y$. Then write $y = x + z$. Then $f(y) = \omega_0 + y = \omega_0 + x + z = f(x) + z$, so $f(x) \leq f(y)$. The fact that both are total orders proves it's an order isomorphism and not just order-preserving.

Obviously, this result generalises a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In fact, I am looking for something other than ordinals and that is why I quote Arthur's answer in my question .... I am sorry to tell you I forget to mention this in my question.